# Find an equation that uses all 9 digits (1-9)

Tags: python

I used Python to write the following program:

```
"""
A desired equation includes a 4-digit integer multiplied with a single-digit integer
to give another 4-digit integer and all 9 digits(1-9) are used in the equation.
"""

import random

found=False

while not found:
    full_range=range(1,10)

    four_digit_num=""
    multiple=""
    for i in range(4):
        four_digit_num+=str(full_range.pop(random.randint(1,len(full_range)-1)))

    single_digit_num=full_range.pop(random.randint(1,len(full_range)-1))

    for i in range(4):
        multiple+=str(full_range.pop(random.randint(1,len(full_range)-1)))

    if int(four_digit_num)*single_digit_num==int(multiple):
        found=True

#output the equation
print "The desired equation is:"
print four_digit_num+"*"+str(single_digit_num)+"="+multiple
```

Is there any better way to perform this task?

Comment: Without getting into the math (because I don't do math). 


four_digit_num=""
multiple="" 
refactors to four_digit_num=multiple=""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is extremely inefficient to do this randomly; you could end up checking the same numbers again and again. For a more structured approach, you could use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations

for nums in permutations("123456789"):
    a = int("".join(nums[:4]))
    b = int(nums[4])
    c = int("".join(nums[5:]))
    if a * b == c:
        print "{0} * {1} == {2}".format(a, b, c)
        break # optional - there's more than one answer!
```

---

Also, note that:

```
found=False
while not found:
    ...
    if int(four_digit_num)*single_digit_num==int(multiple):
        found=True
```

would be neater as:

```
while True:
    ...
    if int(four_digit_num) * single_digit_num == int(multiple):
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

What about simple brute force?

```
def check(i, j, c):
    istr = list(str(i))
    cstr = list(str(c))
    if "0" in istr: istr.remove("0")
    if "0" in cstr: cstr.remove("0")
    Jval = ["%d"%j]
    Set_String = set(istr + cstr + Jval)
    return len(Set_String) == 9

for i in range(1000, 10000):
    for j in range(2, 10):
        c = i * j
        if c < 10000 and check(i, j, c): 
                print "The desired equation is: %d * %d = %d" %(min(i,c), j , max(i,c))i/j, max(i,j))
```

Comment: Can't you just make `i` go in `[1000, 10000[` and `j` go in `[2, 10[` and then consider `i`, `j`, `i*j` ? You should shave off useless checks by considering when the product `i*j` becomes bigger than `9999`.